# How to join polygons and lines vector maps from openstreetmap?

Tags: openstreetmap, grass-gis, vector, routing

I am struggling with the data format OSM gives me: I want to use OSM data for routing, but all round-abouts and parking lots are not in the lines layer. They are situated in the poly(lines) layer.

Thus I could not find a working way to combine both layers by their same type (e.g. highway=secondary) to have the roundabouts in place for valid routing.

I imagine that this is quite a easy one, but I am stuck. can someone help me out?

Frank.

---

After v.patch I added my stations to the network and added missing nodes

```
v.net --overwrite --verbose input=network points=stations output=network_tmp operation=connect thresh=500
v.net input=network_tmp operation=nodes output=network
```

BUT if I now want to do routing, I still get a lot of errors saying that the points are not reachable from each other. On the network itself it looks ok.

```
echo 2 2 4 |v.net.path --overwrite --verbose input=network output=path_2_4
```

I tried a cleanup as found on the web

```
v.clean input=network output=network_cleaned tool=break,rmdupl
```

This does not improve the routing. As the manual says it breaks the lines at each line intersection and therefore all information regarding bridges, tunnels etc. are lost.

Any idea why it is that hard to use openstreetmap data or are my steps wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can extract types with [v.extract](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.extract.html) and then patch them with [v.patch](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.patch.html).

Answer (score 2):

I used now as before

```
v.extract input=lines@PERMANENT output=streets@PERMANENT where=highway='living_street' or highway='service' or highway='pedestrian' or highway='primary' or highway='residential' or highway='secondary' or highway='track' or highway='secondary_link' or highway='tertiary' or highway='tertiary_link' or highway='motorway' or highway='road' or highway='motorway_link' or highway='trunk' or highway='trunk_link' or highway='primary_link'
v.extract input=poly@PERMANENT output=junctions@PERMANENT where=highway='living_street' or highway='service' or highway='pedestrian' or highway='primary' or highway='residential' or highway='secondary' or highway='track' or highway='secondary_link' or highway='tertiary' or highway='tertiary_link' or highway='motorway' or highway='road' or highway='motorway_link' or highway='trunk' or highway='trunk_link' or highway='primary_link'
```

and then

```
v.patch input=junctions,streets output=network --overwrite
```

seems to work now.
 Thanks for your help!

Frank

Comment: Please upvote markusN's answer to give something back for helping you.

Comment: Hi underdark, I also read your tutorial about Finish airports and the use of QGIS/pgrouting. Have you ever tried this with OSM data? In my case pgrouting and the GRASS way do not find reliable routes on the OSM road network. Maybe it is OSM quality related?

Comment: OSM is not routable by default. It needs quite a lot of preprocessing (e.g. splitting road lines at intersections but not at under or overpasses). For PostGIS, I've been using osm2po to make OSM routable.